# How can I kill a Windows Process that refuses to die

Tags: windows, kill

Running Windows Server 2003, I have some processes that when killed take a a few minutes of 100% cpu to die.

Using Process Explorer to view the processes threads I always see 2 threads, with one of them using lots of cpu and stuck in !endthreadex

Any idea what could cause these processes to not-die for so long?
Is there any way for me to force kill such a process?

Comment: Might help to know the processes' name

Comment: Can we to assume you've already tried Task Manager?

Comment: @John, "Process Explorer" is a task manager on drugs: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: If it is on drugs that may be part of the problem.

Comment: Sorry, it seems Process Explorer has grown up. I haven't looked at it for quite a few years.

Comment: the process I'm trying to kill is .Net application that I wrote. It also loads some native dlls. I thought that killing should always work. What could cause a process not to die?

Comment: I'm voting for this question to go to stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 3):

When you try to kill a process, Windows will first attempt to end it gracefully through the normal code paths before taking it down forcefully.  The reason why it's stuck at 100% CPU is most likely that you have a loop or similar in your tear down that is spinning around waiting for something to happen (e.g. like a database connection to completely close) without a Thread.Sleep in it.  It's possible that the something it's waiting for never happens (owing to the abnormal exit caused by killing it) and so it's stuck until Windows decides to take it down by force.  Examine your shutdown code for the process and you should find the culprit for that.

Appropriate for SO at this stage, I would think.

Comment: Does this mean that "kill" is really only sending the process a signal to stop, and then wait for it? Is there a way to control the timeout?